# Include users and membership tables

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4

Here is a simple question: I am using entity framework 4.0 and default sql membership. I need to join my custom customers table to both aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership tables.

This code does not work for some reason:

```
context.Customers.Include("aspnet_Users.aspnet_Membership").ToList();
```

customer.aspnet_Users is always null, although this works fine:

```
context.Customers.Include("aspnet_Users").ToList();
```

This also works:

```
context.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Membership").ToList();
```

So why can't i join both these tables, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
context.Customers.Include("aspnet_Users").Include("aspnet_Membership").ToList();
```

Comment: customers table only connects with users by id, so that doesn't work in my case